# Data Flow - Window Transformation - NTILE Expression

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I'm attempting to assign quartiles to a numeric source data range as it transits a data flow.

I gather that this can be accomplished by using the ntile expression within a window transform.

I'm failing in my attempt to use the documentation provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#nTile) to get any success.

This is just a basic attempt to understand the implementation before using it for real application. I have a numeric value in my source dataset, and I want the values within the range to be spread across 4 buckets and defined as such.

Thanks in advance for any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Window transformation of Data Flow, we can configure the settings keeping the source data numeric column in “Sort” tab as shown below:

[image]

Next in Window columns tab, create a new column and write expression as “nTile(4)” in order to create 4 buckets:

[image]

In the Data Preview we can see that the data is spread across 4 Buckets:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @ShaktiSing-MSFT. This was my attempt, which I find reassuring, unsure as to why my results weren't as expected. We've since utilized a work-around to break the dataset into windows, but I will use your assistance the next time I attempt an nTile Window function.